# Cannot change Android navigationbar color

Tags: java, android, navigationbar

I'm trying to change navigation bar color in my app but the navigation bar is still in this same color.

I've done some research and I've tried all of the following ways:

- [Android lollipop change navigation bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839105/android-lollipop-change-navigation-bar-color)
- [how change navigation bar color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47960026/how-change-navigation-bar-color)
- [How do I change the color of the navigation bar icons? (Android studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210070/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-the-navigation-bar-icons-android-studio)
- [How to change system navigation bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348336/how-to-change-system-navigation-bar-color/27348565)
- https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint

My first thought was that I can't do this programmatically and only thing I can do is to change this color on my phone (LG G6 ) device settings but... I've discovered that some applications like Messenger and WhatsApp are using dark navigation bar.

I've even tried to search for different open source "dark theme" applications, but all of them are using light navigation bar.

How it's possible to use dark navigation bar color if any of the above ways don't work?

Comment: What is your app theme?

Comment: I've tried using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight`.  Both themes give me the same, light navigation bar. Of course I'm still using `android:navigationBarColor` in style.